# I would like to automatically delete older files using forfiles

Tags: windows-10

trying to use *forfiles* to delete files older than *X* days old. I used this code:

`forfiles -p "C:\Users\jukos\Documents\backup_tekdb" -s -m *.* -d -9 -c "cmd /c del @path"`

However, when I run it in a cmd window I get

> ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.

I am able to see the files listed in the directory when I run this line:
`forfiles -p "C:\Users\jukos\Documents\backup_tekdb"`.
I definitely have files with a modification or creation date older than 9 days so I don't see it as being that it's just not finding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for delete files older than 9 days

```
forfiles -p "C:\Users\jukos\Documents\backup_tekdb" -s -m * -d -9 -c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @path"
```

Test this and if work change the "echo" command with "del".

Comment: (or even skipping `-m *`, as that is "the default search mask".)